# ExecutorService with AtomicInteger and Synchronized giving different outcomes

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, compare-and-swap

### Following is the code - AtomicInteger

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ExecutorExample1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executorService.execute(new MyTask());
        executorService.execute(new MyTask());
        executorService.execute(new MyTask());
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}

class MyTask implements Runnable{
    private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            count.addAndGet(1);
            task();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void task()throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println(count + " Enterd Run of: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(count + " Executing: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(count + " Completed Executing: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

### Ouput of above code:

```
2 Enterd Run of: pool-1-thread-1
2 Enterd Run of: pool-1-thread-2
2 Executing: pool-1-thread-2
2 Executing: pool-1-thread-1
2 Completed Executing: pool-1-thread-1
2 Completed Executing: pool-1-thread-2
3 Enterd Run of: pool-1-thread-1
3 Executing: pool-1-thread-1
3 Completed Executing: pool-1-thread-1
```

### Same code replacing AtomicInteger with int and synchronized block

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ExecutorExample1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executorService.execute(new MyTask());
        executorService.execute(new MyTask());
        executorService.execute(new MyTask());
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}

class MyTask implements Runnable{
    //private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private static int count = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //count.addAndGet(1);
            synchronized (MyTask.class){
                count+=1;
            }
            task();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void task()throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println(count + " Enterd Run of: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(count + " Executing: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(count + " Completed Executing: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

### Output of Synchronized block code

```
2 Enterd Run of: pool-1-thread-2
1 Enterd Run of: pool-1-thread-1
2 Executing: pool-1-thread-2
2 Executing: pool-1-thread-1
2 Completed Executing: pool-1-thread-2
2 Completed Executing: pool-1-thread-1
3 Enterd Run of: pool-1-thread-2
3 Executing: pool-1-thread-2
3 Completed Executing: pool-1-thread-2
```

### Question?

1. Why is there a difference in outputs?
2. Why the atomic integer is getting incremented to 2 instead of 1.
3. How do I acheive the synchronised output with atomicinteger.
4. Any benefit or use of using volatile and atomic together?

Comment: The expectation is count maintains the count on the thread executing run method.

Comment: BTW in your second example you increment the variable within synchornized block but when you read it you do not synchronize which might yield visibility problems.

Answer (score 0):

An `AtomicInteger` uses a `volatile` field under the hood. What this does is that it makes sure that all readers (other threads) use the most up-to-date value. When using a simple `int` in your second case, your field is not `volatile` so the `1` you are seeing is coming from a stale value.

By using the `volatile` keyword you should be able to achieve similar results.

Another way would be to use a gate to ensure a condition is met before moving on further. This can be achieved with a `CountDownLatch` for example (there are other ways too): https://www.baeldung.com/java-countdown-latch

Comment: Using atomicinteger why is the count getting incremented from 0 to 2 instead of 1?

Comment: If you run it enough times, you will find cases where it goes to 1 first. When you see 2 first, it just means that both threads executed the increment before printing anything.